# How can I create a new folder using C#.Net for the first use of the application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want when I run my program to create a default folder for it in My Documents for the first use of this application (if a directory with the same name already exists then I want to keep this folder).

This is the code I tried so far:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + @"\MaBib");
```

Comment: What problem have you come up against?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand the question since

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
```

only creates the directory if it does not exist.

[`Directory.CreateDirectory` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, **unless they
>   already exist** or unless some part of path is invalid. ...

Comment: +1, I've always wrapped it in an `if exists` statement but won't any longer. Deleting my answer :)